# Oracle error ORA-65052: statement involves operations with different container scope

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm a relative newb to Oracle. I have set up an instance of Oracle 12c running on a RHEL 7 VM. I am connecting to the database created during installation through and running some installation scripts.

Below is the output from the script that I am trying to run, can anyone point me in the right direction? I have a feeling I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
GRANT CONNECT TO TDSUSER IDENTIFIED BY "TDSPASSWORD"
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-65052: statement involves operations with different container scope
65052. 00000 -  "statement involves operations with different container scope"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to combine one operation that applies to all
           containers with another that only applies to the local container
           into one statement.
*Action:   Execute the operations in separate statements.
old:ALTER USER TDSUSER DEFAULT TABLESPACE &TBLSPC_TDS_TABLES TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &TBLSPC_TDS_TEMP PROFILE &DBPROFILE
new:ALTER USER TDSUSER DEFAULT TABLESPACE users TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp PROFILE TRIDION_SYS

Error starting at line : 6 in command -
ALTER USER TDSUSER DEFAULT TABLESPACE &TBLSPC_TDS_TABLES TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &TBLSPC_TDS_TEMP PROFILE &DBPROFILE
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02380: profile TRIDION_SYS does not exist
02380. 00000 -  "profile %s does not exist"
*Cause:    Try to assign a user to a non-existant profile
*Action:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this Q & A on the Tridion beta Stack Exchange site may help you:

[Oracle Content Delivery CreateTridionSYSUser.sql errors](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12300/oracle-content-delivery-createtridionsysuser-sql-errors)

Basically you need to be in the pluggable database because of the multi-tenancy that is a new feature of 12c.

```
alter session set container=pdborcl;
```